# What is the rank(AB) and rank(BA)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices such that $\operatorname{rank}(A) =n$ and $\operatorname{rank}(B) =n-1$.

Then I know that, $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(BA)  \leq   \min\{ \operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B)\} =n-1$

**My question :**  *Is it true that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(BA) =n-1$?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices of the same order $n$, then
>   $$ \operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{rank}B \leq \operatorname{rank} AB + n. $$

This implies $n-1\le \operatorname{rank} AB$, so that the answer is "yes".

Comment: See the [Sylvester rank inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Properties)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.  In particular, if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with rank $n$ and $B$ is any $n \times n$ matrix, then
$$
\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(BA) = \operatorname{rank}(B)
$$
this fails be true if $A$ has a lower rank.

Comment: Thanks. What will be the rank($AB$), if $A$ has a lower rank? Is there any opinion?

Comment: See Dietrich's answer below: 
$$
\operatorname{rank}(AB) \geq 
\operatorname{rank}(A) + 
\operatorname{rank}(B) - n
$$
that's all we can say without knowing more.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}$Consider that $A$ is invertible, so
$$
\rk(AB)\le\rk B=\rk(A^{-1}AB)\le\rk(AB)
$$
The information that the rank of $B$ is $n-1$ is irrelevant, so long as $\rk A=n$: $\rk(AB)=\rk(BA)=\rk B$.

Comment: I would say, the rank of $B$ is the relevant one when the rank of $A$ is $n$!

Comment: @guestDiego I was referring to the condition that the rank of $B$ is $n-1$, but I agree it was ambiguous.